# How to resolve a latitude/longitude to a polygon in postgis

Tags: postgis, geopandas

I have a list of 13000 places (with latitude and longitude) --- in table : place.
I have a list of 22000 polygons  ---- in another table called place_polygon.
I need to try and resolve the pois to the polygons that they belong to.

This is the query that I wrote :

```
select * from stg_place.place a
left join stg_place.place_polygon b on 
ST_Within(ST_GeomFromText('SRID=4326;POINT('||a.longitude||' '||a.latitude||')'),b.geom);
```

also tried :

```
select * from stg_place.place a
left join stg_place.place_polygon b on 
ST_Intersects(ST_GeomFromText('SRID=4326;POINT('||a.longitude||' '||a.latitude||')'),b.geom);
```

It's running forever. 
But, if I put a filter in the query, then it runs very fast for a single record.

```
select * from stg_place.place a
left join stg_place.place_polygon b on 
ST_Within(ST_GeomFromText('SRID=4326;POINT('||a.longitude||' '||a.latitude||')'),b.geom)
where a.id = <id>;
```

I also tried writing a stored procedure and tried to loop through a cursor to only do for one record at a time. That also didn't help. The program ran overnight with no signs of ending.

Is there a better way to solve this? (not necessarily in postgis, but in python geopy etc... ? )

(Should I consider indexing the tables?)

Comment: Suggest you add a geom column to your places and index that. Then index the geom column in the polygons table. Also, why are you using left join? Do you have points outside the polygons? Also, st_point is probably better than your geom_fromtext line.Also, add table defs, some sample data and your explain analyze statement to your question.

Answer (score 2):

First of all use geography type for your data instead of lat long columns. Why geography, not geometry? Because you use SRID=4326 and with geography type, it will be much easier if you want for example calculate distance in meters then with geometry type which will calculate in degrees for this SRID.

To create geography with your lat long column use function `st_setsrid(st_makepoint(long,lat),4326)::geography`

Ok. Now answering your question on your actual structure

I have a list of 13000 places (with latitude and longitude) --- in table : place. I have a list of 22000 polygons ---- in another table called place_polygon. I need to try and resolve the pois to the polygons that they belong to.

This is the query that I wrote :

```
select * 
  from stg_place.place a 
  left join stg_place.place_polygon b on 
   ST_DWithin (st_setsrid(st_make_point(long,lat),4326),b.geom,0);
```

I used ST_DWithin() instead of ST_Within() because on an older version of Postgres+PostGIS (for sure 9.6 and below) it guarantees of using a spatial index on geoms if created.

Comment: What are the implications of using long-lat instead geography? Performance? I ask because I need some arguments to do that change in the inherited project I work. You demonstrated that it is possible to do st_make_point(long,lat) wherever I need it (at it is in the project I am working at), but maybe that has some drawbacks in performance or something... Thank you!

Comment: The most important thing is of course performance - you can index geography or geometry and PostGIS functions use that indexes to optimize the query.

With geometry/geography format it is easy to find nearest neighbors and do other extensive GIS operations (find the shortest path for example - for this, you will have add another extension "pgrouting")


Without indexed geomerty\geography data, it will be extremely slow to operate with data that have more than few thousands records, and with millions your dataset will be very hard to use without some other special GIS server.

Comment: Drawbacks :
- geometry or geography is not human readable format you have to use functions as st_x() or st_y() or st_asText() to make it readable for humans
- geometry/geography takes more disk space especially when you use indexes (gist index)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! The last is not a drawback, since DBeaver plots the geography in a map and shows it as text :D
About indexes, I have found that the former programmer created the index as `CREATE INDEX location_gis_lon_lat_idx ON location USING GIST(ST_SetSRID(ST_POINT(longitude_deg, latitude_deg),4326));` (and it seems to work) :/
So I don't have any argument against it, although I find it wrong :_(